# sqlplus Error(missing keyword)

Tags: sqlplus

I am using sqlplus to create a table called Person

the script

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Person (
1. _id INT NOT NULL,        
2. name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
3. salary DOUBLE(7) NOT NULL,        
4. CONSTRAINT chk_Person CHECK(salary > 0 AND salary < 1000000)
5. );
```

However I get the following error message

```
ERROR at line 3;
ORA_00905: missing keyword
```

Please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sqlplus doesnot have `double` datatype.You can use `double precision`

## [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/666df)

[SQL: DATA TYPES](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/datatypes.php)